# How to suppress FeedParser INFO messages

Tags: java, rss, feedparser

I am getting spammed with these :

```
de.nava.informa.parsers.FeedParser parse INFO: Channel uses RSS root element (Version 2.0).
```

I am calling it like this:

```
URL feed = new URL(url);
ChannelIF channel = FeedParser.parse(new ChannelBuilder(), feed);
```

I can't figure out from the documentation how to suppress these messages.

does anyone have any experience with this? thanks.

Comment: "spammed" what does that mean? You have some kind of system that will send you emails when parsing a feed fails? You should probably try to log the url for the feed too!

Comment: I mean our log gets spammed. I can log the URL for the feed, but most rss feeds seem to use rss elements are a root and I am not in control of what feeds they are so it really won't help me.

Comment: Also the info in the log is not made manually, it is automatically output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was just that tomcat's logger was set to FINE in /etc/tomcat5.5/logging.properties